# Facebook login for Wordpress FB.api('/me') method doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a php code from a theme to login to Wordpress using Facebook API.  It does not login to Wordpress, but I noticed that it login to Facebook, i.e. when I open another tab and go to facebook, I am already login.  However, failed to login to the Wordpress.  Here is the code.  Help to fix it will be appreciated. I am not a php expert.

```html
<?php $api_settings = $GLOBALS['_webnukes']->fw_get_settings('sub_APIs'); //printr($api_settings);?>

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
   appId      : '<?php echo kvalue( $api_settings, 'facebook_api_key'); ?>', // App ID
   channelUrl : '<?php echo kvalue( $api_settings, 'facebook_channel_url'); ?>', // Channel File
   status     : true, // check login status
   cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
   xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });
 };
  
 //your fb login function
 function fblogin() {
  FB.login(function(response) {
   //...
   if (response.status === 'connected') {
    FWAPI();
   } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    FB.login();
   } else {
    FB.login();
   }
  }, {scope:'email,user_about_me'});
 }

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
  function FWAPI() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  jQuery.ajax({
   url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>?action=_ajax_callback&subaction=fb_login',
   type: 'POST',
   data: response,
   success: function(res)
   {
    if( typeof(res) === 'string' && res === 'success' )
    {
     location.reload();
    }
    if( typeof(res) === 'string' && res === 'failed' )
    {
     alert('Failed to login, Please refresh the page and try again');
    }
   }
  });
    });
  }
</script>


<a class="btn btn-facebook" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fblogin();"><span><?php _e('Sign In with Facebook', THEME_NAME);?></span></a>
```

Comment: why call FB.login inside the callback of FB.login? that does not make any sense, and browsers will most likely block it - for a good reason.

Comment: that being said, "it doesn´t work" is not a sufficient error description. please debug your code. for example, but a console.log(response) at the beginning of the FB.api callback function.

Comment: luschn, thanks for reply.  The error is basically "Failed to login, Please refresh the page and try again"

Comment: "basically"? please post the exact response of the FB.login callback function. your custom error message is not really relevant,l especially because we don´t know what´s inside your admin-ajax.php.

Comment: The error is exactly what I wrote "Failed to login, Please refresh the page and try again."  The admin-ajax.php is not part of theme.  It is from Wordpress core wp-admin/ajax-admin.php

Comment: take a look at the code in your question. that error message is YOUR custom string. i told you twice to put a console.log at the beginning of your FB.login callback.

Comment: Dear luschn,  Thanks for your help.  I do not know much about php coding therefore I could figure out the problem.  I have inserted AO Social Login plugin short code and disabled the above code which shipped with the theme.  I guess that is an easier solution for me then trying to fix the problem in the code. Thanks for your help.